# Libpd configuration in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010, puredata, libpd

I'm trying to import and run the C++ sample project coming with the libpd API [CppTest](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/tree/master/samples/cppTest) within a Visual C++ 2010 project.

I imported the C++ API files of libpd, i.e. PdBase, PdReceiver, PdMidiReceiver and PdTypes, with corresponding source files in the case of PdBase and PdTypes. I put as additional include directories the include folder of Pure Data
("C:\pd_installation_folder\include") and the libpd_wrapper folder containing the C code of the libpd wrapper.

When i run the solution of the sample project it doesn't work due to an error during the linking phase, "error LNK2019" with a huge list of unresolved externals.
What's the problem here?
Should I have any libpd additional static library (or .dll) provided to the linker configuration properties of the VC++ project?

Comment: You typically need to add some directories both to the include and link paths.  You add things to the include path so that the compiler can find third-party headers you `#include`d.  But those are (typically) just the declarations. The linker needs to be able to find the associated third-party libs. So you probably do need to add a library to the linker configuration.

Comment: I know the theory behind compiling and linking phases, the problem is that I can't find any linking library suited for visual c++ into the libpd APIs. It looks like libpd is not compatible with VC++ environment, as there are no resources in the web talking about this configuration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with libpd, but that's not an unusual issue with open source projects.  Many assume a UNIX/Linux like environment, at least a GCC compatible compiler and UNIX-like `make` utility.  It looks like there is a `.sln` file at the top level *libpd* folder ... but it's not uncommon to have to reverse-engineer a `Makefile` and generate a corresponding Visual Studio project file. Good luck.

Comment: why don't you just statically link with `libpd` by adding all libpd sources to your project? also, afaik, the C++-wrapper is a header-only wrapper (but you still need the C-part of the library)